# Navigate urls with Previous and Next buttons via inline frame

Tags: html, mysql, csv

I intend to create webpage that has only an **inline frame** and two buttons (**Previous** and **Next**).

Now here is my problem: I want the two buttons to navigate through a list of urls and display each websites in the **inline frame**. If I click **Next**, it should display the next website via the inline frame, while the **Previous** button displays the previously viewed website.

The url list can be in a **.CSV** or **text file** or **mysyql**, i have no choice.

I have created a static page with inline frame already, which will be hosted on a Linux server. All I need are the buttons and code.

Thanks.

Comment: This community is here to help you do the job yourself, not to do it for you. Attempt the task, put your results on jsfiddle if you need additional help but don't ask people to do the job for you.

Comment: try, and if youwe stuck ask a queation

Comment: I don't know how to do it, that's why I asked. I'm a newbie.